# Should a JWKS URL be hosted by the Service Provider or the OpenID Provider?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, pingfederate

I am wondering if it's a good idea to have the JWKS URI be hosted by service Provider (Pingfederate Server in SP Mode) instead of the authentication OpenId Server.  I currently have a static public JWK available through a URL hosted by my own client web application. the JWKS URL and it's key is publicly open.

Comment: Who is minting the token? PingFederate or something else?

Comment: Hi @AndrewK, what do you mean by "minting the token"  Sorry I am still new here.

Comment: Usually the JWKS endpoint is hosted by whichever one issuing the tokens. I don't fully understand your situation here.

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth server should host the keys used to sign the tokens it issues (i.e., "mints"). The keys of the OAuth server need to be available to clients (the service providers), so it should provide a JWKS endpoint. If the client already has the keys, it can validate the tokens it receives from the OAuth server, and a JWKS endpoint at the server isn't needed per se.